# What can I use to calculate the number of possible routes between 10 locations?

Tags: optimization, word-problem

I have reached a brick wall with a specific issue regarding the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP). I need to calculate the number of possible routes between 10 locations, so I can find out the time it takes for a brute force algorithm to find the shortest one of all. Through some calculations I have reached the conclusion that there is a total of 1, 814, 400 possible routes. However, I have read that there are actually 181, 440 possible routes ([ScienceDirect, https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/traveling-salesman-problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/traveling-salesman-problem)). I believe that 1, 814, 400 is the correct answer (As according to [Marcus du Sautoy, https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p030s6b3](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p030s6b3)) but I am not sure, I have searched and found contradicting information.

This is my first question, I have tried to provide all the necessary information, correct formatting etc. but if I need to adjust anything then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: "*through some calculations*"  What calculations have you personally performed?  It sounds like you only looked for other person's answers

Comment: @MikeDaas the page cited does not give any numbers, it gives a formula, from which OP calculated the value, but the 181,440 is what should be got from the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10!$ routes, but the starting point of the cycle is irrelevant, so you have to divide by 10 for the cyclic symmetry, and then it overcounts by two because there are "anticlockwise" and "clockwise" versions of the same route, so the number of unique roots is
$$
{10!\over 20}=181,440,
$$
so neither of those numbers is correct.

I clicked on the link you provided to support the 181,400 value, and note that the formula there agrees with me, and it doesn't give the value 181,400, so I assume that was your calculation error.

Comment: Hi Suzu, thank you very much for your answer. I've just realized that the when I wrote 181, 400 I had meant to write the answer which you have provided, 181,440. Here was one of my lines of thought: As 3 locations gives 3 possible routes, 4 locations equals 3 x 4 (12); 5 locations equals 5 x 12 (60; 6 locations equals 6 x 60 (360) etc. until 10 locations equals 181, 400 x 10 (1, 814, 400, which is the answer that I got to). Thanks

Comment: @NoahDomingues I don't follow you, do you understand this answer?

Comment: Hi Suzu, I probably didn't explain it properly! So here goes: I wasn't given any specific formula for calculating the possible routes, I thought it might be _n! / 20_ but I decided to go for: _routes for n-1 locations x n_. For example, for 10 locations the calculation would be: _181, 400 x 10_, as 181, 400 is my calculation result for 9 locations. My result for 10 locations matches that of Marcus du Sautoy (as mentioned in my post), but someone must be wrong somewhere, I must be putting the decimal in the wrong place somewhere down the line. Thanks